# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: model\mymodel.h5/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, cx-freeze

I use tensorflow 2.2 with python 3.7 and windows 10. I import a training model with tensorlfow 1.x. When I import with the terminal everything is fine. But when I freeze my code, the file is no longer found.

Here are my files:

```
main.py
   \ codes
     import.py
     \ model
        __init__.py
        mymodel.h5
```

My import.py:

```
from .model import mymodel

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

model = load_model(mymodel)
```

My **init**.py code:

```
from os import path
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    MODEL_DIRECTORY = path.join(path.dirname(sys.executable), 'model')
else:
    MODEL_DIRECTORY = path.dirname(__file__)
    
    
mymodel= path.join(MODEL_DIRECTORY, 'mymodel.h5')
```

The error I got:

SavedModel file does not exist at:
exe.win-amd64-3.7\model\mymode

Answer (score 1):

It's clear you're getting part of the python binary mixed from the message. `sys.executable` is a link to this binary... Probably not what you thought.

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    MODEL_DIRECTORY = path.join(path.dirname(sys.executable), 'model')
else:
    MODEL_DIRECTORY = path.dirname(__file__)
```

I'm pretty sure you want:

`MODEL_DIRECTORY = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'codes', 'model', 'mymodel.h5');`

Also your directory structure is weird...

```
|-|main.py
|-|__init__.py
|-|data
| | |-|model
| | | |-|mymodel.h5
|-|code
| |-|__init__.py
| |-|import.py #wtf is an import.py and why is it down here.
```

`__file__` references the current file so if you have this structure and do this from main.py:

`model_dir = Path(path.dirname(__file__), "data", "model", "mymodel.h5")`
this is using `Pathlib.Path` and `os.path.dirname`.

Comment: Sorry for the late preply, but you tried `mymodel = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'codes', 'model', 'mymodel.h5');` (I know I had model_directory, but technically this applies the whole thing in one go) and still got "SavedModel file does not exist at: exe.win-amd64-3.7\model\mymode"? That sounds impossible. If you can add anything else relevant or confirm you tried the line i put here, try it just above load_model as: `mymodel = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'model', 'mymodel.h5');` And let me know. Assuming you didn't figure this out already.